# Encoding Japanese in Python

Tags: python

I need to encode encode Japanese words to fit the encoding of the word in a link. The problem is when I encode them they're slightly off.

I need it to be:

```
%E5%A4%89%E4%BD%93
```

instead it's:

```
b'\xe5\xa4\x89\xe4\xbd\x93'
```

What can I do to get it to work?

Comment: See the dupe target for a stdlib function that will do what you want for special characters.  Or, alternatively, for *all* characters: `''.join(["%%%02X" % ord(c) for c in s])`

Answer (score 1):

The output starting with `b` isn't an *encoding* per se. It's just how Python represents the raw bytestring. If you type

```
print b'\xe5\xa4\x89\xe4\xbd\x93'
```

you actually get `変体` (if you have a decent terminal/font). The encoding is actually utf-8.

```
>>> x=b'\xe5\xa4\x89\xe4\xbd\x93'
>>> y=u'変体'
>>> x.decode('utf-8') == y
True
```

But then again, if you do

```
>>> urllib.quote(y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1285, in quote
    return ''.join(map(quoter, s))
KeyError: u'\u5909'
```

Because of [this issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue1712522). So have to go back to the bytestring anyway:

```
>>> urllib.quote(y.encode('utf-8'))
'%E5%A4%89%E4%BD%93'
```